# How to open dialog tag with a button in vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, onclick, dialog

I am making a study program where the user can add their assessment tasks to a table to track  them so that they can stay on top of school work. When the user clicks the button to add an assessment task, I want the program to open a popup in the center of the screen allowing them to input relevant info regarding the task. I was thinking of doing this with a dialog tag but I don't know how to get the dialog to open using a button.

```html
<button class="add" @click="">Add new</button>
    <br/><br/>
<dialog open class="window">
  <p>Subject: <input type="text" value="subjectName" placeholder="Subject" v-model="subject"></input></p>
<p>Task: <input type="text" value="taskName" placeholder="Task" v-model="task"></input></p>
<p>Due Date: <input type="date" value="dueDate" placeholder="Due Date" v-model="due"></input></p>
  <form method="dialog">
<button @click="wholeTask.push({subject: subject, task: task, due: due}), reset()">Save</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

I have so far tried putting the dialog into a div and using v-if to toggle whether the div is visible or not, however this didn't work and nothing happened after I pressed the 'add new' button. I also tried using "@click="window.dialog.show();" but I ran into the same issue. I have read other websites that use 'document.getElementById().show' or something like that but I don't know if that would work in vue.

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dialog: false,
    subject: '',
    task: '',
    due: ''
  },
  methods: {
    showDialog() {
      this.dialog = true;
    },
    addTask() {
      this.dialog = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
dialog {
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button class="add" @click="showDialog">Add new</button>
  <br/><br/>
  <dialog :open="dialog" class="window">
    <p>Subject: <input type="text" value="subjectName" placeholder="Subject" v-model="subject"></input>
    </p>
    <p>Task: <input type="text" value="taskName" placeholder="Task" v-model="task"></input>
    </p>
    <p>Due Date: <input type="date" value="dueDate" placeholder="Due Date" v-model="due"></input>
    </p>
    <form method="dialog">
      <button @click="addTask">Save</button>
    </form>
  </dialog>
</div>
```